# ASP.NET unmanaged dll call fails on live server, works locally - repost

Tags: asp.net

I am reposting this. The problem i am having is that my code works on the local development server when i run it through Visual Studio 2010, but when i upload to our host it fails at one of the dll calls. 
My relevant code kinda looks like:

```
IntPtr thingDB = loadDBThing("pathToDB")
If thingDB = 0 then <- check to see if pointer was returned
   display getLastErrorMessage() 
   EXIT SUB
END IF
...
IntPtr thing = createThing(thingDB)
If thing = 0 then
   display getLastErrorMessage() 
   EXIT SUB
END IF
...
IntPtr resultThing = doThing(thing)  <- Code fails here
If resultThing = 0 then
   display getLastErrorMessage() 
   EXIT SUB
END IF
...
IntPtr anotherResultThing = doOtherThing(resultThing)
```

It seems that `doThing()` is throwing an error on the live server but on the the local server everything works fine. The library i am using is a 3rd party library with no support. The server is not throwing an error, but i am able to check the return values of the pointers and get the last error message from the library, though the error string i am getting ('Unknown exception') isnt very helpful. I checked the pointer values for all the result variables and `doThing()` returns a zero value. If i change `resultThing` and the return value of `doThing()` to an `Int64` i actually get a pointer back but then `doOtherThing()` won't accept `resultThing` and i can't convert it back to an `Int32` or `IntPtr`

Wonder if anyone can help explain why this is happening??

OS: Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2
Microsoft-IIS/6.0
ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.3643
Platform String: Win32NT

Comment: There is no error message thrown from the server. I check the pointer value for `resultThing` and call `getLastErrorMessage`. The library i am using is a 3rd party library with no support.

Comment: Are you sure? Check Event Log on live machine, ASP.NET will write any uncaught exceptions there.

Comment: @Alex Ok, I'll look into that.